# Rename all spaces in image file names inside html php files

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, rename, html

Inside different htm.gz, html.gz and php.gz web files I have images and the ones in .jpg format have name with space instead of "-", but in /images/ directory where all images are located they have "-" instead of space

In html file I have "`<img class="photo" width="400" height="600" src="/images/red roses in summer 54.jpg" alt="">`

And in directory "/images/" all are listed fine with "-" between words like this "red-roses-in-summer-54.jpg"

So, what I want is a bash command/script that searches in all htm.gz, html.gz and php.gz files inside /var/www/domain.com and find all .jpg images and replace space with "-". So from /images/red roses in summer 54.jpg to have /images/red-roses-in-summer-54.jpg

Server is running on centos 7 if it's important.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the names within the zipped (tar?) archives?

Comment: Have you even attempted to script it yourself, or are you asking for a service?

Comment: @MichaelVehrs yes, if possible.

Comment: @Peschke Well, if I have the right commands I can make a bash script in linux, but if you can build it I'm fine to pay if price is reasonable

Comment: @user2627132 - No pay necessary, I was just curious.

Comment: @Peschke my linux knowledge is say for beginners. I run my own server and do all commands in bash, from updating, backups to load balancing but for this situation I don't want to play if i can get some help from here

Comment: That's pretty difficult. However, `tar` has a `transform` option, which might be helpful.

Comment: ok, I can transform all html, php and htm pages from gzip to normal, so no more compression impediment, so what to do in the other situation? How can I get the results I need?

Comment: Let's start from the point that I have htm, html and php web files, no gz. In this conditions, how can I solve the problem with the images?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, this should be done in a language like `perl` or `python` which have good HTML parsing libraries.  But if you want to do it in a shell script, you can install the [xml2](http://ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/) package, which provides tools called `html2` and `2html` for converting HTML to and from a flat-file format suitable for use with line-oriented tools like `sed`, `grep`, `awk`, etc.

It also contains similar tools for working with XML and CSV files.

Then you can use `sed` to transform spaces on matching `img src` lines to dashes.  Then convert back to html.

For example, using your sample html line:

```
$ cat file.html 
<img class="photo" width="400" height="600" src="/images/red roses in summer 54.jpg" alt="">

$ html2 < file.html  | sed -e '\:/img/@src=/images/: s/ /-/g' | 2html 
<html><body><img class="photo" width="400" height="600" src="/images/red-roses-in-summer-54.jpg" alt="">
```

Redirect the output from that to, e.g., `file.new.html`.  and then `mv -f file.new.html file.html` if you want to replace the original file with the modified version.  I very strongly recommend keeping a backup copy of the original files so that you can revert to a known-good starting point if you make a mistake.

BTW, the flat-file format produced by `html2` looks like this:

```
$ html2 < file.html 
/html/body/img/@class=photo
/html/body/img/@width=400
/html/body/img/@height=600
/html/body/img/@src=/images/red roses in summer 54.jpg
/html/body/img/@alt
```

`xml2` is packaged for Debian and Ubuntu and probably other Linux distros.  If it's not available pre-packaged for your unix, you can find the source code at the link above.

There are many ways to make these changes in lots of files.  Here's a simple `for` loop example.

```
for htmlfile in *.html ; do

   html2 < "$htmlfile" |
       sed -e '\:/img/@src=/images/: s/ /-/g' |
       2html > "$htmlfile.new" \
   && mv -f "$htmlfile.new" "$htmlfile"

done
```

WARNING: test that this does what you expect **before** running it on lots of HTML files.  And keep a backup of the originals.  If the HTML in your files is not completely valid HTML (i.e. if it won't pass a HTML syntax checker) then `html2 | ... | 2html` could make your html files even more broken than they already are.

If there are too many files, or the files are in multiple subdirectories, you'll have to use `find ... -exec`.  There are countless examples of using `find` here on this site.

Comment: I need this to work on approx 200000 pages, so doing 1 image by 1 isn't the case.  Maybe a way to search in each page for any .jpg image that is in tag src="/images/

Comment: Anything you do to one file can be done to 200000, or any number of files.  Use a `for` loop.  or `find ... -exec`

Comment: soory to bug with my noob question, but can you please give more details. I have approx 200000 files that the bash script/command need to look after. About find command, this is one: find /var/www/domain.com -type f ! \( -name '*.yml' -o -name '*.cgi' -o -name '*.pl' -o -name '*.db' -o -name '*.sqlite' -o -name '*.feed' -o -name '*.com' -o -name '*.xml' -o -name '*.gz' -o -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.pdf' -o -name '*.js' -o -name '*.css' -o -name '*.ico' -o -name '*.gif' -o -name '*.png' -o -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.jpeg' \) -exec

Comment: I installed xml2 package for centos but above bash script gives me error " 2html: command not found" Any suggestion from here?

Comment: is `2html` actually in the `xml2` package in Centos?  maybe the centos devs decided to split it into two packages.  i don't know, I don't use centos.

Answer (score 0):

I've found something but doesn't work well:

```
find /var/www/domain.com -type f ! \( -name '*.db' -o -name '*.sqlite' -o -name '*.feed' -o -name '*.com' -o -name '*.xml' -o -name '*.gz' -o -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.pdf' -o -name '*.js' -o -name '*.css' -o -name '*.ico' -o -name '*.gif' -o -name '*.png' -o -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.jpeg' \) -maxdepth 1 -exec sed -e '\:/img/@src=/images/: s/ /-/g' {} \;
```

This opens all files, looks inside, BUT doesn't change anything. 
Any suggestions?